# Getting future contracts market cap data using python

Tags: python, yfinance, pandas-datareader

Im trying to calculate my portofolio's risk and i need to calculate the market cap. it seems yahoo finance info attribute no longer provides market cap. what should I do?

Comment: Have you done any websearches for alternatives to yahoo finance for market cap? If so, what did you find and why did it not solve your issue? If not, please do a search and show your research in the question.

Comment: actually yes i did try both yfinance and pandas_datareader. it seems yahoo finance provided market cap before but now yf.Ticker(ticker).info doesnt contain market cap. seems its depricated for some reason

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you searched for (I presume you did more than 1 search), what you found and why it didn't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

The `info` attribute doesn't appear to work anymore. See [#1407](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/issues/1407).

An alternative is to use [yahooquery](https://pypi.org/project/yahooquery/) library which uses an unofficial API instead of web scraping. Here is how you would obtain the market cap of a stock using `yahooquery`. [Try it out in Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1DUWS2Nrsd77rsx3fQFMWdtJMIPrySmVx?usp=sharing).

```
import yahooquery as yq

ticker = 'AAPL'
yq_ticker = yq.Ticker(ticker)
yq_ticker.price[ticker]['marketCap']
```

Result:

```
2363791769600
```

Note: As you see in my Google Colab example, I had to use `requests` version 2.28.2 and `urllib3` version 1.26.14 to get it to work.